# Loop till the value of variable is not zero

Tags: php, html, twig

I have been stuck at this for a while now. I am new to twig and i am trying to iterate a code untill my variable becomes zero. I have tried this:

```
{% set total = 5%}
      {% set i=1 %}
        {% for total %}
          <a href="#" class="page">{{i}}</a>
          {%set i=i+1%}
          {% set total = total -1%}
        {% endfor %}
```

and this

```
   {% set i=1 %}
    {% for total > 1%}
      <a href="#" class="page">{{i}}</a>
      {%set i=i+1%}
      {% set total = total - 1%}
    {% endfor %}
```

but none are working.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `untill my variable becomes zero.` -- which variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twig `for`s are more akin to PHP's `foreach`s (they are for iterating over a traversable). To achieve what you are describing you would do:

```
{% set nums = range(1, 5) %}
{% for num in nums|reverse %}
    <a href="#" class="page">{{ num }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

In practice, you could set `nums` from your controller logic. Also note from the Twig [manual](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html):

> Unlike in PHP, it's not possible to break or continue in a loop.

You can, however, skip elements with `if`. Manual example:

```
{% for user in users if user.active %}
```

Comment: I am setting variable total form controller only. Its value is 5. Now I want to generate a tags 'total' number of times. This is my problem.

Comment: Simply insert that `total` into the `range` call.